# C# loop for drives hangs

Tags: c#, loops, freeze, drive

I am trying to find the drive letter ("C:\" for instance) of a drive. 
I know the name of the drive("KINGSTON" for instance), and store it in the string `drivename`. 
`sDir` is the string that holds the result.

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

foreach (DriveInfo d in drives)
{
   MessageBox.Show(d.Name);
   if (d.VolumeLabel.Contains(drivename))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Got Ya");
      sDir = d.Name;
      break;
   }
}
```

This piece of code seems to me like it should work, though, eventhough i have 6 drives (drives.Lengt also shows 6), it only loops through 3 of them, without ever getting into the if (never shows the "got ya" msgbox), and then just jumps out of the if-sentence, this code is wrapped in.

Comment: Are you sure it's not throwing an exception? If you debug into it, then hit "break" when it appears to be hung, what happens?

Comment: How long have you left it to "hang" for? It might be that it's trying to access a network drive, CD, or similar, and you need to wait for that access to timeout?

Comment: Did you step through your code to check exactly where it hangs?

Comment: Try also to check IsReady (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.driveinfo.isready.aspx)

Comment: It wasnt in a try catch before, and it didnt stop debugging.
I wrapped it into a try catch, and youre right, it gives the exception "System.IO.IO.Exception: The Device is not ready" on either the line "d.Name" or "d.VolumeLabel..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DriveInfo.VolumeLabel` might throw an exception, you must handle it properly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.driveinfo.volumelabel

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives(); 

foreach (DriveInfo d in drives) 
{ 
   MessageBox.Show(d.Name);
   string volumeLabel = null;
   try
   {
     volumeLabel = d.VolumeLabel;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     if (ex is IOException || ex is UnauthorizedAccessException || ex is SecurityException)
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     else
       throw;
   }
   if (volumeLabel != null && volumeLabel.Contains(drivename)) 
   { 
      MessageBox.Show("Got Ya"); 
      sDir = d.Name; 
      break; 
   } 
}
```

You could also check [`DriveInfo.IsReady`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.driveinfo.isready).